# Renaming file fails strangly

Tags: android

im trying to rename a file simply, but every time it returns false, and i have tested every thing, every thing is Ok, i have no idea what is happening:

```
File file = new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza.jpg");
boolean success = file.renameTo("somethingelse.jpg"));
```

this is a simple file renaming and i have the external storage read/write premissions , i am sure the file exists there, am sure path is Ok, because i have Tested them all!

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /><uses-  
permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest)
```

dest should be a full path, not just a filename. What you are doing is moving the file under a new name.

Should be:

```
 boolean success = file.renameTo(new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/somethingElse.jpg"));
```

Comment: We've all been there :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File renameFrom = new File(sdCardPath,"ABC.png");
File renameTo = new File(sdCardPath,"DEF.png");
renameFrom.renameTo(renameTo );
```